# Installation of extensions using CLI have issues composer require

Tags: magento2

The following error are showing tho run the commad :

```
composer require igorludgero/outofstocklast


brasilma@a2ls18 [~/public_html]# composer require igorludgero/outofstocklast
Using version ^1.0 for igorludgero/outofstocklast
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
**Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.**

Problem 1
- Installation request for igorludgero/outofstocklast ^1.0 -> satisfiable by igorludgero/outofstocklast[1.0.0].
- Conclusion: remove magento/framework 100.1.2
- Conclusion: don't install magento/framework 100.1.2
- igorludgero/outofstocklast 1.0.0 requires magento/framework ~100.0.4 -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.0.10, 100.0.11, 100.0.12, 100.0.13, 100.0.4, 100.0.5, 100.0.6, 100.0.7, 100.0.8, 100.0.9].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.10].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.11].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.12].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.13].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.4].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.5].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.6].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.7].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.8].
- Can only install one of: magento/framework[100.1.2, 100.0.9].
- Installation request for magento/framework (locked at 100.1.2) -> satisfiable by magento/framework[100.1.2].

**Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

magento 2.1 requires magento framework 100.1.* but the module your are trying to install only allows version 100.0.* (roughly)

so the either the module does not support magento 2.1 or (more likely) the module vendor used a composer constraint that just not works with magento 2.1